# Javascript - bypassing sort attempt yielded weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sorting

### The story

I am using [Choices](https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices) library, which is quite great except for one little thing - it is trying to sort all the options when it is given select tag. It accepts two fields to controll sorting `sortFields` and `sortFilter`. From the source code it seems that first option is only using for searches (that I'm not using), so I am left with a second option that is being passed to Array's `sort` function just before library builds its template. I thought giving it `function() { return 0 }` should do the trick (as it will treat all elements as equal and hence won't reorder array), but apparantly it is not the case.

### Findings

It seems that `sort` method behaves very weirdly when given `constantly 0` function. Examples:

Chrome (Linux + Chrome 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit)):

```
compare = function() {return 0};
[50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500].sort(compare)
> [50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500] // All fine up to 10 elements

[50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550].sort(compare)
> [300, 50, 150, 200, 250, 100, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550] // Can't even say what sort of order this is
```

All fine on Firefox.

Is it a Chrome bug? Is there any other better way of disabling sorting using only sorting function?

(Yes, I am currently working on patch for the library to disable it without hacks. Question has purely "academic" status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the .sort() comparator returns 0, the sort function may re-order the elements. The JavaScript .sort() mechanism is not guaranteed to be stable, and a non-stable sort can do exactly what you've observed.

A *stable* sort is one that does not re-order elements that are already in order when the process begins.

Think of it this way: when the comparator returns 0, the sort mechanism interprets that as meaning, "the two elements have the same sort order, so it doesn't matter what order they're in".

Not all JavaScript runtime systems use the same sort, so that's why results can vary between platforms.

Comment: It all makes sense - but why would it switch two values if they order doesn't matter. It seems chrome is using bubble sort for up to 10 elements (for which 0 function works) and then switches to some smarter sorting mechanism, which explains 10 elements threshold. Question holds though, is it possible to bypass `sort` function using smart comparing function?

Comment: It's just a by-product of some implementation detail probably. Your best bet is probably to patch that library as you mentioned and log a pull request. There's no JavaScript API to affect the behavior of `.sort()`.

Comment: There is now a 'shouldSort' flag to disable sorting entirely: https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices#shouldsort - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=90

It's a know problem for item lenght > 10, because of a different sort algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's V8 JS engine switches to insertion sort instead of quick sort for short arrays:

```
  // Insertion sort is faster for short arrays.
  if (to - from <= 10) {
    InsertionSort(a, from, to);
    return;
  }
```

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/30f8d3354334e7424324429d4e525a3b67b2b8bd/src/js/array.js#L809

To get a sort that is always stable, you'll have to use an alternative stable sort function, such as [Underscore's sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy).